# Adding custom dimension for User scope on custom events in GA4

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

In our GA4 implementation we've added a custom dimension to track the user_id like so:

```
gtag('set', 'user_properties', { user_id: 'TEST' })
```

And this allows us to filter our data using this dimension successfully. However if we send a custom event like this:

```
gtag('event', 'CUSTOM_EVENT', { event_category: 'data', event_label: 'data', event_value: 'data')
```

When we filter the data using our custom dimension we get 1 for All Users, but 0 for our custom dimension.

[image]

It's almost as if using a custom event doesn't take into account the `user_id` we'd set globally... do you need to explicitly pass the `user_properties` for custom events? And if so how?

According to the documentation here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/12370404?sjid=5067103890801170547-EU#zippy=%2Cgoogle-tag-websites it should be sending this data for ALL events.